# Comparing one file to another

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I made a form which is basically an activity for users to improve their Korean number skills. I have one file which has 10 numbers in English and another file which has those 10 numbers translated in Korean. So far I have randomized 5 labels so that it picks 5 numbers out of the 10 numbers in the file which i put as a list.

I'm having problems when the user answers the question f the user got the answer correct then a tick image should appear however the code that checks if the user has the correct answer doesnt work. When the user enters the correct value into AnswerBox1 it doesn't show a tick which it should checking if the user got the answer correct.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim rand As New Random
    Dim attempt As Integer
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim QuestionFile As New IO.StreamReader(CurDir() & "\" & "NumbersQ.txt")
    Dim fileContentsQ As String = QuestionFile.ReadToEnd
    Dim fileListQ As New List(Of String)
    Dim AnswerFile As New IO.StreamReader(CurDir() & "\" & "NumbersA.txt")
    Dim fileContentsA As String = AnswerFile.ReadToEnd
    Dim fileListA As New List(Of String)
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For Each Str As String In fileContentsQ.Split(CChar(vbCrLf))
            fileListQ.Add(Str)
        Next
        For Each Str As String In fileContentsA.Split(CChar(vbCrLf))
            fileListA.Add(Str)
        Next
        Dim randItem As Integer = rand.Next(0, fileListQ.Count - 1)
        Question1.Text = (fileListQ.Item(randItem))
        fileListQ.RemoveAt(randItem)
        'removes the question from the list so that the question won't be repeated
        a = randItem
        Solution1.Text = fileListA.Item(a)
        'a hidden label which contains the answer to the question
        fileListA.RemoveAt(a)
    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckAnswers_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckAnswers.Click
        If AnswerBox1.Text = Solution1.Text Then
            Tick1.Show()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What is the problem you're having? Is "AnswerBox1.Text = Solution1.Text" not true at the time CheckAnswers is Clicked?

Comment: When I enter the correct value into AnswerBox1 it doesn't show a tick which it should

Comment: When you debug the Click event, do the values look similar?

Comment: Also for some weird reason when i physically copy and paste solution1.text into answerbox1.text it would give a tick but when i manually type the answer into answerbox1.text which is identical to solution1.text it doesn't give a tick

Comment: You don't have any special characters like tabs, etc in your text files do you? That would be one reason why copying/pasting works but typing does not.

Comment: The NumbersA text file is saved in a Unicode format on a notepad